# How to allow Telegram bot to read messages in a private channel that I'm in (not the bot)?

Tags: telegram-bot

I want to create a Telegram bot that can read all of the messages in a private channel that I'm in (the bot does NOT belong to this channel), then forward all of the messages to another group that the bot is a member

This is technically possible because people did it already: https://telegrambotting.com/tg_feed/start

In my thinking, there should be 2 steps:

1. Allow the bot the read the messages in a private channel that I'm in.

Technically, I think that there should be a mechanism so that I can create a token for my account, this token will grant access to the bot to read all the messages that I can read (or messages in channels/groups that the token specifies)

2. Once the bot can read the messages, forward the messages to another group using the simple sendMessage method https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage

I'm stuck at step 1.

So how to allow the Telegram bot to read messages in a private channel that I'm in (not the bot)?

Comment: Could you find your answer?